# jquery fullcalendar with coldfusion

Tags: jquery, json, coldfusion

I am trying to add a event calendar to my coldfusion application. I want to use the jquery fullcalendar plugin for this. I did some research, I understand that I need to write a CFC which has to return data (event) in the json format.

I am kind of stuck as to where to start from. I have the fullcalendar code from the wbsite http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/download/. I need to add events which are coming from coldfusion queries to the calendar. I have never used jquery or json before, also was not able to find any documentation . So, please guide me to start off. thank you in advance.

Comment: WHat have you tried? Can you show some code? What happened to what you tried? Have you even googled anything? When I google JQUERY COLDFUSION this is one of the first pages I get http://ja.mesbrown.com/2009/10/coldfusion-and-jquery-using-ajax-to-call-a-cfc-and-return-json/

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with importing events from the database. But I finally found a solution. Its based on Raymond Camden's plugin for fullCalendar, but not as complex as his plugin. You can find the original plugin here http://www.raymondcamden.com/2011/6/17/FullCalendar-jQuery-Plugin

In this version, you have to add an extra script along with the rest script needed for fullcalendar. Write it in the page where you want the calendar. Then call the cfcomponent stored in a cfc page (mine is inside components folder and is called calendarEvents.cfc). The cfc is used to obtain the data from the database and convert it to the array format needed for fullcalendar events.

First call the calendar in the cfm page

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inner block-header"></div>
    <div class="span10">
        <div id='calendar'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Along with the rest of javascript imports needed for fullcalendar, add this script. Write it after fullcalendar call.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
        //Formating
        header: {
            right: 'prev,next today',
            left: 'title',
            center: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        titleFormat: {
            month: 'MMMM yyyy',
            week: 'MMMM d[ yyyy] - {[ MMM] d, yyyy}',
            day: 'dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy'
        },
        columnFormat: {
            month: 'dddd',
            week: 'dddd <br> MM/dd',
            day: 'dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy'
        },
        timeFormat: {
            '': 'H(:mm) TT \n '
        },
        //Click function to switch to daily agenda
        dayClick: function(date, view) {
            $('#calendar')
            .fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaDay')
            .fullCalendar('gotoDate', date);
        },
        //Data Feed
        events:'components/projectManagerEvents.cfc?method=getEvents&returnformat=json',
        editable: false,
        weekMode:'variable',
        ignoreTimezone:false        
    });
});
```

Now for the cfc page.

```
component {
    url.returnformat="json";
    remote function getEvents()
    {
        var q=new query();
        q.setDatasource("bugTracking"); 
        q.setSQL("select projectName, estimatedEndDate from projects");
        var dbresults=q.execute().getResult();
        var results=[];
        for(var i=1;i<= dbresults.recordCount;i++)
        {
            arrayAppend(results,{
                "title"=dbresults.projectName[i],
                "start"=dbresults.estimatedEndDate[i]
            });
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        aspectRatio: 1.45,
        weekMode: 'variable',
        editable: false,
        header: {
            right: 'today basicWeek month prev,next'
        },
        eventSources: [
            { color: 'green', url: '/webservice.cfc?method=myMethod&Parameters=Maybe' },
            { url: '/anotherwebservice.cfc?method=myOtherMethod' }
        ], // eventSources
        eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

        }, // eventClick
            eventMouseover: function( event, JsEvent, view ) {

        }, // eventMouseover
        eventRender: function( event, element ) {

            } // eventRender
    }); // $#calendar.fullCalendar      
}); // ready
</script>
```

Have your web service CFC return in JSON format, the Event object must contain title and start date (UNIX timestamp).